# search match beetwen three conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a script that search match but i think that this way not is the best because is so long, i know that maybe it can be more short but i don't know much things about **regexp**.

I need get all string that start with **http** but also i need get if inside string contain **youtube.com** or **youtu.be** and i created this **regexp**:

```
^(?=.*\bhttp)(?=.*\byoutube\.com\b).*$|^(?=.*\http)(?=.*\byoutu\.be\b).*$
```

but i guess that maybe something like it work:

```
^(?=.*\bhttp)(?=.*\byoutube\.com\b|\byoutu\.be\b).*$
```

Comment: `/https?:\/\/\S*?youtube\.(?:be|com)/i` is going to fail to match `youtu.be`

Comment: @ionizer: You're right. I overlooked 2nd part. Regex should be: `/https?:\/\/\S*?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)/i `

Comment: I think that looks like the answers found in Mr. Polywhirl's comment, and I think we just needed to add the `http` part to be required. Though specific to this question, regex like these should be enough: `/^(http:\/\/)(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/?/i`, unless you want more optimized ones...